# What is a question with multiple answers called?

Tags: meaning

A multiple choice question is the one with several choices of which only one choice is correct.

What type of question is the following? It has multiple answers.

> Which of the following are planets?
>       1) Jupiter
>       2) Moon
>       3) Mars
>       4) Earth
>       5) Sun

Comment: Looks like there are multiple answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term *[multiple response item](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_choice_question#Structure)* has been used for multiple choice questions where several answers are correct.  Variants of multiple choice or response questions include *[extended matching items](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_matching_items)*, for which a group of choices is given up front and applied singularly or plurally to following questions; *[true, true and unrelated](http://forum.quoteland.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/99191541/m/6161038631)*-type questions; and less-well-known  *[Paul Revere questions](http://blogmedconference.blogspot.com/2010/07/inception.html)*.

The [blog entry](http://blogmedconference.blogspot.com/2010/07/inception.html) just mentioned does not  define *Paul Reveres*, but contains an example.  The question, "BlogMed 2011 would be used to:" is followed by choices 1 through 4 and the remark "The answer is C, 2 and 4!".  That is, C stands for choices 2 and 4 being correct, 1 and 3 not.

Answer (score 5):

The term I've always heard and used myself is the one you give, ***a multiple choice question***.

Comment: Funny enough, in Israel these are called "American questions."

Comment: Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_choice_question

Comment: If the one I have mentioned is a Multiple choice question, how would you call a question with only one correct answer?

Comment: @Mark -- is that because (a) questions of that kind are found on American standardized tests, (b) American tourists tend to ask that kind of question, (c) to make fun of Americans generally, or (d) all of the above?

Comment: @RagunathJawahar: I'd never heard of a different term to mark the distinction between questions where only one answer is correct and those where there's more than one answer. I'd always known "multiple choice question" for both. But jwpat7's answer gives new information to me as well, therefore it is the answer you should accept.

Comment: Good question @Malvolio. I don't really know the answer but it seems to be based on (a), the assumption that American standardized tests are multiple choice. The funny thing is no matter how many Israeli standardized tests have multiple choice questions they still call it 'American.'

Comment: Yeah, @Mark, that was mostly meant as self-referential humor.  But to your answer: probably Americans eat more French fries than French eat *pommes frites*, but we still call 'em French fries.